# How can I filter a specific field out of Rails SQL logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, activerecord, logging

I know about filter_parameter_logging for request params, but that only works for request parameters.  I don't want to certain private user data in the logs, but I do want debug level logging.  I am hoping for a better solution that monkey patch ActiveRecord and do a replace on the SQL string.

For reference, this is a Rails 2.3 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a good way to do this. Looking at how active record is logging the statements, there is no way to filter a column other than parse the string in some way.